# grep capturing a word group

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I am trying to extract `CONFIG_X86_ACPI_CPUFREQ` from 
obj-$(CONFIG_X86_ACPI_CPUFREQ). I want to generalize this for other 
options that might be available - like

`XXX-$(YYYY)` - so I want to extract only `YYYY`'s from this string in shell script.

I did it like this -

```
# echo "obj-\$(CONFIG_MMC_SDHCI)" | cut -d"\$" -f2 | cut -d"(" -f2 | cut -d ")" -f1 
CONFIG_MMC_SDHCI
```

But I am sure there must be a more cleaner way to do this using grep only. Is there nay way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way:

```
x='XXX-$(YYYY)'
$ echo $x | awk -F'[)(]' '{print $2}'
YYYY
```

Taking the delimiters as `'('` and `')'`, `awk` will have the required field in the $2.

**Updated**:

Using grep:

```
$ echo $x | grep -oP '(?<=\().*(?=\))'
YYYY
```

The `-P` option of `grep` is used for Perl like regex. This expression tells anything preceeded by a `'('` and followed by a `')'`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sed`:

```
echo "obj-\$(CONFIG_MMC_SDHCI)" | sed 's/.\{3\}-\$(\(.*\))/\1/g'
```

You can use ... instead of `.\{3\}`
If you are sure that your stuff comes in between parentheses only, then you can further simplify it as:

```
sed 's/.*(\(.*\))/\1/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $x | perl -ne '$_=m/.*\$\(([^\)]*)\)/;print $1'
```